# Require() from string into object

Tags: node.js, require

Assuming I have the content of a js file in a string. Furthermore, assume it has an `exports['default'] = function() {...}` and/or other exported properties or functions. Is there any way to "require" it (compile it) from that string into an object, such that I can use it? (Also, I don't want to cache it like `require()` does.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very simple example using [`vm.runInThisContext()`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinthiscontext_code_options):

```
const vm = require('vm');

let code = `
exports['default'] = function() {
  console.log('hello world');
}
`

global.exports = {}; // this is what `exports` in the code will refer to
vm.runInThisContext(code);

global.exports.default(); // "hello world"
```

Or, if you don't want to use globals, you can achieve something similar using `eval`:

```
let sandbox     = {};
let wrappedCode = `void function(exports) { ${ code } }(sandbox)`;

eval(wrappedCode);

sandbox.default(); // "hello world"
```

Both methods assume that the code you're feeding to it is "safe", because they will both allow running arbitrary code.